# SQL JOIN same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have one table with "ID", "Sequence", "Status":

```
    ID | Seq | Status
    ======================
    10 | 001 | 010
    10 | 002 | test
    10 | 003 | 005
    11 | 001 | 010
    11 | 002 | 338
```

The result from my query should give me the complete table plus an extra column with the status for the highest sequence for the respective ID:

```
    ID | Seq | Status | LStatus
    ======================
    10 | 001 | 010    | 005
    10 | 002 | test   | 005
    10 | 003 | 005    | 005
    11 | 001 | 010    | 338
    11 | 002 | 338    | 338
```

I have no clue how to do it. I startet with something like that:

```
SELECT a.*, b.status as lstatus
FROM table a
left join (select top 1 b.status from table b order by b.seq DESC) 
on a.id = b.id
```

Hope you can help me :)

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a group by max for the subquery and join the base table

```
  SELECT a.*, b.status as t.lstatus
  FROM my_table a
  INNER  join (select id,   
            max(b.status) lstatus 
            from my_table b 

              group by id)  t on t.id = a.id and
```

for numeric value only

```
  SELECT a.*, b.status as t.lstatus
  FROM my_table a
  INNER  join (select id,   
            max(b.status) lstatus 
            from my_table b 
            where IsNumeric([b.status])=True
              group by id)  t on t.id = a.id and
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say: Status Could also be something different, e.g. text. So max wouldn't work in my case

Comment: then  which is the logic for this column  .. how you choise the value you need?

Comment: anyway answer  updated  with a suggestion for numeric

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ROW_NUMBER()` to assign number to each row within the ids ordered by seq. Join that back to your table where the id matches and the rownumber `rn` = 1.

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SVZDBH68610)**

```
SELECT 
  a.*
, b.status
FROM table a
JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.Table) b ON a.id = b.id AND b.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

```
with status as (
Select distinct(id),status from table order by seq desc)select a.*,s.status as LStatus from table a,status s where a.id=s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `subquery` here:

```
select *, 
       (select top 1 Status from table where id = t.id order by status desc) as Lstatus 
from table t;
```